# Ubuntu doesn't recognize me having more than 1 OS

Tags: 12.04, installation

I'm trying to Install ubuntu 12.04 by following the instruction found in its official documentation on http://ubuntu.com  to install it alongside win7, but this is what I found

[image: screenshot]

Is there anything I can do to get ***install the ubuntu alongside win7*** option just like on its websites?

Btw, I'm using HP ProBook 4331s.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Proceed cautiously!  You can safely choose "Something else" and you will be shown how your hard drive is arranged and from there it might be easier to make a decision.

If, for example, have only one partition and it is entirely taken up by Windows, you'll need to do a bit of rearranging, such as shrinking the Windows partition and leaving some unallocated space for use by Ubuntu.  If this is the case, I'd suggest shrinking the Windows partition from within Windows itself and just leaving the freed-up space as unallocated.  Then, when you boot again from CD, DVD, or USB to install Ubuntu, it'll show you another option, i.e. to install Ubuntu next to Windows.

How big you make your partitions (Windows & Ubuntu) will depend upon the size of your hard drive and upon how you plan to use things, but I'd recommend giving Ubuntu at least 50 or 60 GB to get started.

Comment: I can't shrink my C volume more than MBs, so I'm shrinking my D instead. So it's Ok to install ubuntu on my D right??

Comment: Yep.  Ubuntu will be fine on that partition -- which Ubuntu won't call D.  Linux partitions are called things like sda, sdb, sdc, etc., and the order isn't always as you might expect.  Anyway, Ubuntu is fine being installed on other partitions.